# Brillouin Zone of honeycomb lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics

Why is the Brillouin zone of a honeycomb lattice is a hexagon and not a parallelogram? I mean, how can you get the hexagonal BZ using  the reciprocal lattice vectors?

Comment: The brilluoin zone is a parallelogram. But because of the periodicity, you can cut the Brillouin zone apart and patch it back together in many shapes. Convention is a hexagon.

Answer (score 1):

Brillouin zone is a symmetrized cell, so called [Wigner–Seitz cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell). Parallelogram doesn't reflect point symmetry of your reciprocal lattice, while hexagon does, thus hexagon is chosen as the Brillouin zone instead of parallelogram.